# RecursionError at /form/movie/ maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django, orm, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I am not quite sure how manytomany fields work in django. so what i have here is a profile model where in the name field i want to add the username that i will get from the login credentials, and movies will be added from a form that was created using the movie model. I'd like to understand what's wrong in the views.py file here. Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Mxs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralQG.png)

my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Framework(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="name")
    # name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.movies
```

my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from . models import Article, Comment, Movie, Character

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
            'pub_date'
        ]

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'name',
            'body'
        ]
```

class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Movie
    fields = [
        'name'
    ]
```

class CharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Character
    fields = [
        'name'
    ]
```

my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Movie, Character, profile
from .forms import MovieForm, CharacterForm
# Create your views here.
def characterset(request):
    # form = CharacterForm(request.POST or None)
    # if form.is_valid():
    #     form.save()
    #     form = CharacterForm()

    form2 = MovieForm(request.POST or None)
    if form2.is_valid():
        form2.save()
        form2 = MovieForm()



    context = {
        'form2' : form2
    }

    return render(request, "manytomany/form2.html", context)

def movieset(request):
    current = request.user.username
    print(current)

    modelname = User.objects.get(username=current)
    print(modelname)

    a = profile(name=modelname)
    print(a)


    form = MovieForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.save()
        a.movies.add(f)
        a.save()

    # form2 = MovieForm(request.POST or None)
    # if form2.is_valid():
    #     form2.save()
    #     form2 = MovieForm()



    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, "manytomany/form.html", context)

def show(request, id):
    a = Movie.objects.get(id = id)

    c = Character.objects.get(id = id)

    c.movies.add(a)

    return render(request, "manytomany/show.html")
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! Please consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Django page with the error. It references `return self.movies` this is due to the relationship you established for that particular model.

So whats happening is this:

Profile -> Movies -> Many-To-Many -> Profile

See whats happening here? You're going in circles and broke Django by having a "circular reference". What you could do is remove the offending line:

```
class profile:
    ...
    __str__(self):
        return self.name # or something like it
```